# Appropriate chapel ownership for fields

Tags: chapel

What is the appropriate ownership to use for object fields created in init?  I thought it was best to use "owned", but it looks like it doesn't preserve those after the init has finished.

Running this code...  ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBBboMwEDzbr1hxKUiInHqJlQf0kJz6ARecxCo2kbFK04q30901UNqeag7Yu7OzM1Nf9c2001S3uu/hpJ2BTykBz5sOEM17hD30MVh/Uam@21lvo9Wt/TCBK7fQ1UDF3NP8gi@QCeYTr7avmO0ABFLcGROjYIIh2GieEZfzLdC4EOle8a/1@cpTKClGnJUjCjK@ge7M6qVMTo6dfzX3xYsgM7O407qeq/pCReuj2or566b8Rm6NCVbESHRmBugGbxpewvOF@gUllgNxzRowg3/4z54eHGhwyR0taCArYRVR0ktjHIRbGrgM63A3OvTQtU2VcXpym902NYmHonE/LKVenr1oj99Z1wb5H5Fp1eb2tNIVapq@AA))

```
class Name {

    var text : string;

    //initializer
    proc init(name : string) {
        this.text = name;
    }

        proc writeThis(writer) {
        writer.writeln(this.text);
    }   
} //end of Name

class Monkey {

        var name : Name;
        var age : int;

        proc init(name : string, age : int) {
            this.name = new owned Name(name);
            this.age = age;
        }

    proc writeThis(writer) {
        writer.writeln("I'm a monkey named ", this.name, ", and I'm ", this.age, " years old.");
    }

} //end of class Monkey



var m = new owned Monkey("bananaface", 5);
writeln("m: ", m);
```

... causes it to print only:

```
m: I'm a monkey named
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVBBboMwEDzbr1hxKUiInHqJlQf0kJz6ARecxCo2kbFK04q30901UNqeag7Yu7OzM1Nf9c2001S3uu/hpJ2BTykBz5sOEM17hD30MVh/Uam@21lvo9Wt/TCBK7fQ1UDF3NP8gi@QCeYTr7avmO0ABFLcGROjYIIh2GieEZfzLdC4EOle8a/1@cpTKClGnJUjCjK@ge7M6qVMTo6dfzX3xYsgM7O407qeq/pCReuj2or566b8Rm6NCVbESHRmBugGbxpewvOF@gUllgNxzRowg3/4z54eHGhwyR0taCArYRVR0ktjHIRbGrgM63A3OvTQtU2VcXpym902NYmHonE/LKVenr1oj99Z1wb5H5Fp1eb2tNIVapq@AA)

In the Monkey's init, what would be more appropriate ownership than setting this.name = new owned Name(...)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried your program with the pre-release 1.19 version (which is coming out soon) and it printed out

```
monkeys.chpl:20: In initializer:
monkeys.chpl:21: error: Field name would outlive the value it is set to
```

Now I will explain the problem:

```
class Name { ... }
class Monkey {
  var name : Name;
  proc init(name : string) {
    this.name = new owned Name(name);
  }
}
```

is equivalent to

```
class Name { ... }
class Monkey {
  var name : borrowed Name;
  proc init(name : string) {
    this.name = new owned Name(name);
  }
}
```

which is the same as

```
class Name { ... }
class Monkey {
  var name : borrowed Name;
  proc init(name : string) {
    var tmp = new owned Name(name);
    this.name = tmp.borrow();
    // the instance in tmp is automatically deleted here
  }
}
```

And there you can perhaps see more clearly that the result of `new owned` is destroyed at the end of the initializer.

The fix is simple: declare the field as `var name: owned Name;`:

```
class Name { ... }
class Monkey {
  var name : owned Name;
  proc init(name : string) {
    this.name = new owned Name(name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I clearly missed a lot of the places I should have been declaring ownership when I was going through the new language spec.  It's correct to have it owned both at the field-declaration and in the initialization?

Comment: Yes. When migrating code over, or if you're migrating your brain over, I recommend using `--warn-unstable` to flag any un-decorated class types. (For example, that flag would ask you to always use `unmanaged Name`, `borrowed Name`, `shared Name`, or `owned Name` rather than just `Name` which used to mean something like `unmanaged Name` and now means `borrowed Name`.

Comment: I meant that I missed the places in the chapel documentation where it clearly explains the semantics behind all of these changes and how to go about making them.

Comment: Are you aware of https://chapel-lang.org/docs/language/evolution.html ? Another relevant docs link is https://chapel-lang.org/docs/primers/classes.html